# Mount a CMIS location as file system in Linux?

Tags: linux, webdav, cmis

[CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) (Content Management Integration Service) is aiming to be the new webDAV. Is there a possibility to either mount a CMIS source in Linux or integrate it into Nautilus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## CmisSync

There was no convenient tool for this, so I started developing [CmisSync](http://CmisSync.com).

It will keep a local folder synchronized with your files in the CMIS repository. It allows you to browse your CMIS documents offline. [Open Source](https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync).

Comment: Any help I can offer?

Comment: @stwissel: yes, there are a number of different things to do, so any help is very welcome! Please contact me at nicolas.raoul AT gmail.com Thanks a lot!